# How do I get my raid array back and mounted after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, mount, partition, mdadm

I had created a raid-1 array for two drives (sde and sdf) using the normal mdadm process and had created it under md1 and mounted it to /mnt/storage. After a reboot md1 no longer exists. My /mnt/plex works fine. Did my array go away or do I just need to point the partition to the correct mount point?

Running `lsblk` gives me

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0  63.4M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1974
loop1         7:1    0  63.5M  1 loop  /snap/core20/2015
loop2         7:2    0  40.8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/19993
loop3         7:3    0 111.9M  1 loop  /snap/lxd/24322
loop4         7:4    0  40.8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/20092
sda           8:0    1   7.3T  0 disk
└─md0         9:0    0  21.8T  0 raid5 /mnt/plex
sdb           8:16   1   7.3T  0 disk
└─md0         9:0    0  21.8T  0 raid5 /mnt/plex
sdc           8:32   1   7.3T  0 disk
└─md0         9:0    0  21.8T  0 raid5 /mnt/plex
sdd           8:48   1   7.3T  0 disk
└─md0         9:0    0  21.8T  0 raid5 /mnt/plex
sde           8:64   0   3.6T  0 disk
sdf           8:80   0   3.6T  0 disk
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 930.5G  0 part  /
```

Running `blkid` gives me

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="255C-50C9" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="26565297-8615-4534-88b8-a160ab111fe4"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="ac32d63a-e8dc-4f58-b677-507491ed46de" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="25fa09fa-6781-49bf-927c-89e721f71154"
/dev/sdd: UUID="8051a9fa-3272-6a40-3950-5897a2b600f4" UUID_SUB="cb838ac3-6c2a-bfb0-fd0d-f7c63c447aa3" LABEL="tron:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdb: UUID="8051a9fa-3272-6a40-3950-5897a2b600f4" UUID_SUB="e4209087-7804-1e66-c3d2-dfef0f898b73" LABEL="tron:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/md0: UUID="f81c3ae4-363f-453a-ab49-1e716b27fc3b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdc: UUID="8051a9fa-3272-6a40-3950-5897a2b600f4" UUID_SUB="f8da02fe-22e3-6f55-880d-c1d52c78167e" LABEL="tron:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sda: UUID="8051a9fa-3272-6a40-3950-5897a2b600f4" UUID_SUB="d6bfc2f7-056d-441a-023f-25d73804c456" LABEL="tron:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdf: PTUUID="e6979b33-6f82-11ea-96f0-0026b98cb28a" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sde: PTUUID="e6a40000-6f82-11ea-96f0-0026b98cb28a" PTTYPE="gpt"
```

And here is what's in my `/etc/fstab` Note: I uncommented the last two lines because it was causing a timeout issue, which uncommenting helped and it doesn't hang, but this is probably part of the issue

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ac32d63a-e8dc-4f58-b677-507491ed46de / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/255C-50C9 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
/dev/md0 /mnt/plex ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0
#UUID=489c654c-58e8-4187-b478-b37bc6af81f9 /mnt/storage auto defaults,x-parent=f87a9a2f:b87b822b:60dc9e96:9d59d84f 0 0
#UUID=489c654c-58e8-4187-b478-b37bc6af81f9 /mnt/storage auto defaults,x-parent=f87a9a2f:b87b822b:60dc9e96:9d59d84f 0 0
```

If I don't uncomment the last two lines I get the following [timed out waiting for device](https://imgur.com/a/sDfsyxM)

Comment: You can't mount two drives to the same mount point. Tou need mount disk 1 for example to /mnt/storage1 and disk 2 to /mnt/storage2. Make sure those directories exist in the filesystem

Answer (score 0):

You can't mount two drives to the same mount point. You need mount disk 1 for example to /mnt/storage1 and disk 2 to /mnt/storage2. Make sure those directories exist in the filesystem

Comment: Not what I'm trying to do. The two drives were in a RAID 1 array, which is the end goal, however when I rebooted they were no longer in an array, and I'm trying to get my data back.